# Why hashmap has 'hash' in its name?

Tags: c++, hashmap

Hashmap is just a data structure which is implemented using self-balancing binary search tree, having a (key, value) pair. So if we consider a string as our key, then the balancing/construction of tree happens by comparing string values only.

Ex: (Ab, 1) (Aa,1)

Here the tree construction takes place by comparing Ab and Aa as strings, rather than some hashed value.

So when does the hashing (function) take place? Or is it just in the name of hashmap and there's no real hashing inside hashmap?

Comment: What is "hashmap", there's no such class in the C++ standard library. There is [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) which is typically implemented as a tree, and there's [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which is a hash-table implentation.

Comment: This is a general computer-science question rather than a programming question; a question specifically about terminology rather than solving a problem; and one that I would expect is better answered by either a textbook or a web search.

Comment: As Some programmer dude mentioned, there is no such thing in C++ standard library. [`hash_map`](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/hash_map.html) is actually a part of STL (**This class is an SGI extension; it is not part of the C++ standard.**) And the description (working, using RB tree) you've written here is of `std::map`. Hash maps do involve "hashing". You can do a simple web search on "internal implementation of hashmap". It will show you results of `java.util.HashMap`. But that's the similar data structure as implemented in the STL.

Comment: 'Hashmap is just a  data structure which is implemented using self-balancing binary search tree, having a (key, value) pair`: no it isn't. Your question is based on a false premiss.

Answer (score 1):

No, a hashmap is not a self-balancing tree.

A hashmap us typically implemented using an array of buckets, where the entries are stored in a bucket whose position in the array is calculated from the hash-value of their key.

Since multiple, different entries can have the same hash key, each entry in the array can store a list of entries with the same hash key.

Comment: If this is `std::unordered_map` which is the "hashmap" for c++, then this doesn't sound right. `Since multiple, different entries can have the same hash key, each entry in the array can store a list of entries with the same hash key.` -- hash keys are different, but organised into groups in memory to make access to elements cheaper.

Comment: Simple example: You store integers in a hash map of size 7 and calculate the hash like "value modulo 7". Then the values 3 and 10 and 17 etc. all have the same hash key, 3, and are stored in the same bucket list. To reduce such "hash collisions" you can change the size of the array, use another hashing algorithm etc. but the principle stays the same.

Comment: Ahh so you are not referring to `std::unordered_map`